# Can I forward to a HttpPost method without a BeginForm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post

I'm new to MVC and still haven't found a way to do this.

In the view I have this Clone button:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Clone", "Game", new { pModelId = Model.Id })" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Clone Game</a>
```

And in my Controller this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Clone(int pGameId)
    {
        int lClonedGameId = mGameRepository.CloneGame(pGameId);
        return RedirectToAction("Show", new { id = lClonedGameId, message = "Your game was cloned succesfully" });
    }
```

I'm getting a 404 due to the [HttpPost] but I don't want to make it [HttpGet] since it writes to the DB. Is there a way to make that button go to the HttpPost method without a BeginForm or something like that?

Comment: Links always mean GET requests. If you want the browser to make a POST request, you need a form. The fact that you are using MVC makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is only a matter of having link instead of button to submit the form I suggest you adding a form and using javascript to submit a form when the link is pressed (below code assumes you are using jQuery):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Clone", "Game", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "form1"}))
{
    //Your other elements go here
    <a href="#" class="cloneGameSubmit">CloneGame</a>
}
```

And hook the script:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.cloneGameSubmit").click(function () {
        $("#form1").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that you will need a hidden field with a `name` attribute of `pGameId` in order for it to bind to the action method parameter.

Comment: I tried this but still need to figure out about that hidden field =P, I need to read a lot about web.------Just found the way to do it. Thank you, your answer was the exact thing I needed.